# NodeJS межмашинная коммуникация

Tags: node.js

Есть группа виртуальных машин в рамках одного хостинга.

Они должны общаться (внутри хостинга) с неким сервисом на VPS (к сервису шлют запросы и он выдает ответ).

Подскажите пожалуйста - какой способ коммуникации на Ваш взгляд будет быстрее всего (c меньшими накладными расходами):

1. стандартный rest на tcp
2. grpc
3. websocket
4. Redis PUB-SUB
5. node-ipc
6. что то из стандартного Node:
   https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/net.html
7. возможно я забыл что то еще

Сейчас планируется до 1000 сообщений в секунду, каждое сообщение меньше 512 байт.

Comment: 1000 сообщений на один инстанс ноды? А далее что делать с этим? Рассылать веерно другим серверам?

Comment: это небольшой микросервис, который выдает первый свободный proxy. решил сделать на 'node:net' - createServer. Этот же подход использует node-ipc - но она ранее удаляла все файлы с компьютера - поэтому пользоваться страшно